# Change float caption formatting

Tags: formatting, captions

My question refers to the floats specifiers. For instance, figures have specifier **Figure #:** *Blah blah blah...*, i.e., the type (**Figure**), the number (**#**), the colon (**:**), and then the caption (*Blah blah blah...*).

My question is: is there a way to change **Figure 01:** *Blah blah blah...* to **Figure 01 -** *Blah blah blah...*?! I mean, is it possible to replace the colon by the dash?

Comment: You can use the caption package to configure this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of thing is best achieved using the [`caption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/caption). It provides many default features and customizations, as is shown in the example below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{topnumber}{3}% Just for this example
\usepackage{caption}

% Define a custom caption separator for use with labelsep key-value
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{dash}{~--~}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}% Put something on the page

\begin{figure}[t]
  \caption{A figure}% Default caption format
\end{figure}

\captionsetup
  [figure]% Float type
  {%
    name      = Image,
    labelfont = bf,
    textfont  = it,
    labelsep  = period
  }

\begin{figure}[t]
  \caption{Another figure}% New caption format
\end{figure}

\captionsetup[figure]{%
  labelsep  = dash
}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \caption{Yet another figure}% Use default with dash separator
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`\captionsetup[<type>]{<key-value csv>}` takes an optional `<type>` if you want the setting to be specific to a particular float. Without it, it would apply to all floats using the traditional `\caption` interface.